# Setting up Social Sign On - Trailhead question

Tags: authentication, trailhead, registration-handler, social-sign-on

I am currently on the trailhead and working on the following question:

[Identity Management for Social Sign On](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_social?trail_id=identity)

when I get to the part where it directs

Copy URL displayed in Test-Only Initialization URL > Paste URL into a browser

The trailhead suggests that I should be getting a facebook log in page but it only gets the XML when I do it. I am running google chrome Version 106.0.5249.121. I usually do not care about such an error like this (much of the later trailhead is dealing with this error).

But when I go through the following steps of updating the registration handler with the handler that they link to from GitHub and refresh the page it still only shows the XML! It does not actually get to facebook social log in.

Possible issues that I can see:

1. When I looked back over it, I found that I was copy/pasting the URL that salesforce gives for the configuration page. I made sure to copy paste the URL that salesforce gave for the experience site that I was building (customers). I copy pasted that into the browser with the same result of

paste url into browser > XML appears > (upon browser refresh) browser displays the message of "unable to authenticate"

2. I have tried the redo it method several times getting the same result - authentication error

- Delete the authorized provider and re-initialize
- Delete the registration handler and re-initialize
- Unlink facebook social sign on from the experience website and re-initialize

the XML that the URL picks up is:

```
<user>
<network_id>0DB8Z000000GpKx</network_id>
<full_name>John Doe</full_name>
<provider>Facebook</provider>
<org_id>00D8Z000003CzJl</org_id>
<last_name>Doe</last_name>
<id>10101912546588138</id>
<portal_id>000000000000000</portal_id>
<first_name>John</first_name>
<email>john.doe@gmail.com</email>
</user>
```

so it is clear that the user is being passed to the test URL for the experience website. Could it be that because John Doe doesn't necessarily have a facebook account that Facebook can't authenticate it? do I need to test this out with a real facebook account, and pass real facebook credentials of this user to facebook? How do I set the facebook credentials of this user?

Long story short, I want to complete this exercise and allow people to sign into my experience website using their social sign on.

Comment: It likely means you are logged in to FB already. You can try using the same URL again in an incognito window.

Comment: Thank you for this - after following your suggestion, now I can sign onto my experience web site - but now it only gets through the log in page, then gets redirected to the same XML page that popped up (as shown in the opening post). I am still not getting through to the page. So I am not sure why I am getting the XML pop up again.

Comment: thank you @manjit5190

Comment: The test only URL will only show the XML. You may want to use the SSO or OAuth URL.

Comment: Thank you @manjit5190 ! I have the social sign on working!